# Unable to import library error in Anaconda base environment VScode

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am working in the base environment with Anaconda and VSCode. I have been facing a problem while importing TensorFlow libraries, especially with Keras.

[image: code]

I can still run the code and it works, but it sometimes hinders in autocorrection while writing the code.

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Please post a [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) and errors in detail. We can't think anything from your question so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned, even though the warning shows up on VSCode but works perfectly fine when executing the code on the Anaconda terminal, the issue might not necessarily be with the Tensorflow library but with the autocomplete feature of VSCode itself.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26813) that can help you understand what's actually going on in VSCode.

The issue is mostly just IDE/Editor related, and if you want the autocomplete features to work properly, you could try using V1 api of Tensorflow.

Comment: Thank you, Alen. I had already visited the link you provided and tried everything mentioned there, but no luck.

Comment: You're Welcome, Mayank! I'll update the post if I do come across anything relevant!